# Iterating a json to get next value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to iterate a json which has many elements. 
Sample json

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "abc",
  "namespace": "abc.abc.abc",
  "doc": "Last Updated Date",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "COLUMN_1",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "string(500)",
      "default": " "
    },
    {
      "name": "COLUMN_2",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "string(1)",
      "default": " "
    },
    {
      "name": "COLUMN_3",
      "type": "int",
      "doc": "decimal(1,0)",
      "default": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "COLUMN_4",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "string(1)",
      "default": " "
    }
  ]
}
```

I need a code that can provide me a map of values like

```
map = <COLUMN_1,String>
      <COLUMN_2,String> 
      <COLUMN_3,INT>
      <COLUMN_4,String>
```

basically the map should have .

Comment: It would be better to show us what you've tried so we are able to help instead of just giving you a solution. There are plenty of answers to this question in detail on Stackoverflow already.

Answer (score 0):

For map all items from json, you should use js **map** method.

Here you can find more information: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

`json.fields` - this is reference for object array.

Map method gives you possibility to iterable by all elements:

```js
json.fields.map(item => {
 console.log(item.name)
 console.log(item.type)
 console.log(item.doc)
 console.log(item.default)
})
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context explaining how this code will solves the OP's question. Code-only answers are discouraged. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25446762)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data` variable holds your JSON data:

```
const dict = {};

for (let key in data) {
   dict[key] = data[key]
}
```

Note that `fields` for instance will store the entire array

If you would like to get only the types (instead of values), change this line

```
dict[key] = data[key]
```

To

```
dict[key] = typeof data[key]
```